# Android Web Service Null Value Return

Tags: android, web-services

I am a starting bud to develop project in android . I try to get .NET Web Service from android using KSOAP . But when i recieve value from the webservice i get output null°F as output. Please find the fault in my program.

```
package com.example.webservice;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebService extends Activity {
       private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
       private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl";
       private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
       private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String result=getFarenheit(et.getText().toString());
            tv.setText(result+"°F");
            }
        });
    }
    public String getFarenheit(String celsius){
        SoapObject request= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo celsuiusPI= new PropertyInfo();
        celsuiusPI.setName("Celsius");
        celsuiusPI.setValue(celsius);
        celsuiusPI.setType(double.class);
        request.addProperty(celsuiusPI);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope (SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("WebService output", response.toString());
            return response.toString();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Input and Output Image

[image]
[image]

LOGCAT :

```
11-15 15:31:42.215: W/System.err(1058): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-15 15:31:42.215: W/System.err(1058):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
11-15 15:31:42.215: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
11-15 15:31:42.215: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
11-15 15:31:42.225: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-15 15:31:42.225: W/System.err(1058):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-15 15:31:42.225: W/System.err(1058):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
11-15 15:31:42.225: W/System.err(1058):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
11-15 15:31:42.235: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
11-15 15:31:42.235: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-15 15:31:42.246: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
11-15 15:31:42.246: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
11-15 15:31:42.246: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:117)
11-15 15:31:42.246: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
11-15 15:31:42.246: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
11-15 15:31:42.246: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
11-15 15:31:42.246: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
11-15 15:31:42.255: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
11-15 15:31:42.265: W/System.err(1058):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
11-15 15:31:42.265: W/System.err(1058):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:120)
11-15 15:31:42.265: W/System.err(1058):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:176)
11-15 15:31:42.265: W/System.err(1058):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
11-15 15:31:42.275: W/System.err(1058):     at com.example.webservice.WebService.getFarenheit(WebService.java:58)
11-15 15:31:42.275: W/System.err(1058):     at com.example.webservice.WebService$1.onClick(WebService.java:41)
11-15 15:31:42.275: W/System.err(1058):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-15 15:31:42.285: W/System.err(1058):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-15 15:31:42.285: W/System.err(1058):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-15 15:31:42.285: W/System.err(1058):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 15:31:42.285: W/System.err(1058):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 15:31:42.305: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-15 15:31:42.305: W/System.err(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 15:31:42.305: W/System.err(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 15:31:42.315: W/System.err(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-15 15:31:42.315: W/System.err(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NetworkOnMainThread Exception occurs when we try to hit network services from main thread**

to avoid this You have to call web services in sub thread,Handler or in asyncTask, Your problem will solved

Comment: could u please give me a example

Comment: In your on click method start a AsyncTask and in aysnctak doInbackground call your get ferenheit  method and onPostExecute of AsyncTask update tv.setText(result);                                                                                                  


something like this

private class TemperatureTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

@Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
//Your Function
result=getTemp();
}

 protected void onPostExecute(String jsonPostResponse) {
tv.setText(result);
}

Comment: getTemp();no such methods in my program

Comment: //Buddy use function name here, I am here to help you not to figure out keep everything according to your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396890/android-soap-webservice-asynctask-app-force-stop-error see this i had tried but ends with appication force stop error