# Android soap webservice Asynctask app force stop error

Tags: android, web-services

i have wrote a program in android for webservice using soap. but iam not aware of asynctask. Can some one Correct the program flow. I need to send a integer value and get converted value thru webservice

```
   package com.example.webservice;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import com.example.webservice.R.string;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebService extends Activity {
       private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
       private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl";
       private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
       private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    String celsius="";
       Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    String res;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String result=getFarenheit(et.getText().toString());
            //tv.setText(result+"°F");
            new service().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    private class service extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            SoapObject request= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo celsuiusPI= new PropertyInfo();
            celsuiusPI.setName("Celsius");
            celsuiusPI.setValue(celsius);
            celsuiusPI.setType(string.class);
            request.addProperty(celsuiusPI);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope (SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try{
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                Log.i("WebService output", response.toString());
                res= response.toString();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return res;

        }
         protected void onPostExecute(String h){
             String result=h;
                tv.setText(result+"°F");

    }


}
}
```

Trace

```
11-15 18:38:08.045: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:08.065: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:08.065: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:08.515: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:08.515: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:08.546: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:08.546: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.130: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.130: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.167: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.167: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.685: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.685: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.736: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:09.736: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.235: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.235: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.255: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.255: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.801: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.801: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.825: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
11-15 18:38:10.825: W/Trace(823): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace when it force closes?

Comment: Don't roll over exceptions and print a stacktrace.You need to handle it or re-throw it. Bottom line here is something is null. Might have been easier to debug if you didn't roll over the exception.

Comment: From the stacktrace either `res` or `tv` must be `null` within `onPostExecute`

Comment: I believe it's `res` that is `null`.

Comment: Within the onPostExecute, before doing anything with res, make sure it is not null. Also, make sure that you have bound tv properly, so that it is not null.

Comment: I am on proxy so i believe that proxy doesnt allow to send value so what can i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        request.addProperty("XMLMarks", pXmlString);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003;
        envelope.xsd = SoapEnvelope.XSD;
        envelope.xsi = SoapEnvelope.XSI;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);



        final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // final SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        Toast.makeText(this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String str = response.toString();
        strcheck = str;
    }
```

Comment: null value at where? if the response is null then try to have a look at your webservice

Comment: WebService works fine but my doubt is iam on proxy whether this makes the emulator blocked from sending or receiving da